# Problem installing Perl module Java::Import

Tags: java, installation, perl-module

I am trying to install the [Java::Import](http://search.cpan.org/~rusekd/Java-Import-0.03/lib/Java/Import.pm) module on my Win32 system for Perl 5.10. But I can't seem to get it install from cpan. Here is the error I get when I try to install it via CPAN:

```
    gcc -c -I"src" -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPRIVLIB_LAST_IN_INC -DPERL_I
MPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -
O2 "-DXS_VERSION=\"0.03\"" "-DVERSION=\"0.03\"" -I"C:\Perl\lib\CORE" -I"\include" -o "lib\Java\Wrapper.o" "lib\Java\Wrapper
.c"
Access is denied.
error building dll file from 'lib\Java\Wrapper.c' at c:/perl/lib/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Platform/Windows.pm line 143.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
  RUSEKD/Java-Import-0.03.tar.gz
  nmake test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports RUSEKD/Java-Import-0.03.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I tried to look at the cpan-testers & seems like there is bug for compilation errors since 2006. Has any one ever been able to install this module? There seems to be another module called [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::Java). Am I better off using that one instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java::Import [cannot pass its own unit tests on any platform](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Java-Import%200.03;maxver=1). `Inline::Java` has its quirks, but it is definitely useable.

Comment: Disclaimer: I use it with Cygwin but have not tried it on a pure Win32 platform.

Comment: I am not trying to do much. I just have to import a Java class to get some of our custom defined exceptions that we use in our internal system. So, with that simple requirement in mind is it sufficient to use Inline::Java or is there some other preferred way?

Comment: @John - that sounds like something `Inline::Java` should be able to handle. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -c -I"src" ... -o "lib\Java\Wrapper.o" "lib\Java\Wrapper.c"
```

=> Access denied

So `lib\Java\Wrapper.o` is not writable. Either you have no permissions to write into that directory or that `Wrapper.o` file already exists and is blocked by another process.